# Is a link only answer pointing to Documentation an answer?

Tags: discussion, documentation, link-only-answers

Can I limit my answer to a link to documentation?

- If the answer is positive won't it degrade the quality of the Q&A site? [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) says:

  > Provide context for links
  >
  > Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

  Documentation is part of Stack Overflow so quoting or worrying about going offline shouldn't matter.
- If the answer is negative should I worry about content duplication?

Comment: No freaking no. Documentation changes nothing the answer status. Answer should answer the question as it is.

Comment: OK, but "close as duplicate of documentation page" is now my new wet dream. My Border Wall, if you will.

Comment: @Braiam I feel the same but how do you justify in "new order"?

Comment: "Docs are part of SO so quoting or worrying about going offline shouldnt matter." So only provide context, but maybe reduce the relevant part because the target is very unlikely to become unreachable.

Comment: The duplicate on this questions does not seem correct, since you can not duplicate to documentation. I think it merits an answer related only to documentation link only answers, for example that we consider that it should be a comment not an answer.